# Initializing from a pair in constructur intializer list

Tags: c++, member-initialization

I have a function `f` returning a pair of objects of classes `A` and `B`:

```
auto f() -> std::pair<A,B>;
```

Furthermore, I have a class `C` that has `A` and `B` as members:

```
class C {
  public:
    C();
  private:
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

In the constructor of `C`, I want to use the member initalizer list and initialize with the output of `f`:

```
C(): a(f().first), b(f().second) {}
```

This calls `f` twice though and it is a quite complicated function.
Is there a way to achieve this using the member-initializer list without calling `f` twice? The internal structure of `C` can unfortunately not be changed.

Comment: What's stopping you from adding ctor `C::C(A , B)`  ?

Comment: This could be a solution, but it is changing the interface of the class which is not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Improving on the idea from [AnkitKumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71009766):

```
class C
{
    A a;
    B b;
    
    C(std::pair<A,B> &&pair) : a(std::move(pair.first)), b(std::move(pair.second)) {}

  public:
    C() : C(f()) {}
};
```

Comment: Nice! This construction in particular enables to basically create a temporary in the member intializer list.

Comment: If there is another function `g(A a)` dependent on `a` for initializing `C` and `D` with the returned `pair<C, D>` another constructor 'level' can be introduced. Alternatively `f` can return a quadruple of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` with just one constructor 'level'. This would also be the only way, if complicated program flow is involved. So every function can be translated into initializer lists without introducing additional members for storing temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
class C {
  public:
    C(std::pair<A,B>);
  private:
    ...
};

C(pair<A,B> p): a(p.first), b(p.second) {}
```

You'll now call `f` only once, which will work so long as it doesn't contradict some other requirements.

Comment: And then you can make the constructor private, and call it from `C()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i did not think of that, but yep! That would be be a better solution than this maybe, thanks!

Comment: The constructor signature you suggest won't work in the given scenario: a rvalue cannot be converted to a non-const reference

Comment: @fabian my bad, corrected, thanks